# How to send SOAP object to client over the web service?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, web

As I am new to web services. I have to send a SOAP object in response to a client. So the client will parse the SOAP object and retrieve the values from it.

Here is an example of a SOAP response which I have to send:

```
Struct{
    returndata=[
         Struct{
              status=update; 
              url=url; 
              chksum=123ddd456ccc8775; 
         }
    ]; 
 }
```

Comment: NOTE: what you showed is not an example of a SOAP response. [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) protocol uses **XML** for its [message format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP#Message_format).

Comment: Check these tutorials out: [JAX-WS Hello World Example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example-document-style/); [JAX-WS Five Minute Tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world); [JAX-WS Deployment Five Minute Tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-deployment-five-minute)

Comment: I think you are talking about "serialization".